# Rails parameter from hidden_field won't pass to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a search controller in which I get the client from params.

```
def show
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])
  @training_session = @client.training_sessions.new
end
```

In the form I am trying to pass the client_id value:

```
<%= form_for @training_session do |f| %>
  <% binding.pry %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :client_id, value: @client.id %>
```

But in training_sessions_controller params[:client_id] is nil.

```
private
def find_client
  binding.pry
  @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
end
```

Why is the client_id parameter not passing from the form?

Answer (score 2):

First take look to the HTML form generated by the view.
However in your controller you should get your client id as:

```
training_session_params = params.require(:training_sessions).permit(:client_id)

client_id = training_session_params[:client_id]
```

Because the form is created for the TrainingSession model and not for the Client one.